# What is the comparative analysis of avidya on different states/manifestations of Siva: Parasiva, Siva, Sadasiva, Iswara?

Tags: shiva, advaita

According to Advaita, avidya can be defined as the knowledge of the existence of multiple things. In fact, there is one and only one single soul and is manifested in many ways.

There are at least four states of Siva I am interested in for this question: Parasiva, Siva, Sadasiva, and Iswara.

Parasiva is the state before creation and can be compared to an ocean without waves.

Siva is the state where there is a creation and can be compared to an ocean with waves.

I am not sure how to understand Sadasiva and Iswara. But this question is not on this.

I want to know the component of avidya in all four states. It is clear that avidya in Parasiva state is zero. Although I believe the same is true for Siva, I am not sure.

In which states does the phenomenon of avidya present and please present the ratio of avidya in comparison among the states?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give complete answer but the word "Shiv" is used to refer to both Rudra/Ishvar and Sadashiv/Parashiv. From Shiv Puran Section 2.1 - Rudra-saṃhitā (1): Sṛṣṭi-khaṇḍa, Chapter 16, 49-50

> Śiva is the Supreme Brahman. The three deities, Viṣṇu, I and Rudra are His manifestations according to the difference in the attributes.
>
> **His perfect and complete incarnation is Rudra. He is Śiva himself.** The five-faced lord has made His beautiful mansion in Kailāsa. Even if the whole Brahmāṇḍa were destroyed, it knows no destruction.

Rudra is just a complete incarnation, not the original one himself. Vishnu & Brahma are incomplete/defective. That's why Rudra is referred to as Shivji many times.